# PyLint. Что значит dangerous-default-value

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть следующая функция

```
def pg_select(sql: str, data: dict = {}) -> list:
    """
    SELECT
    :param sql: sql-запрос
    :param data: Данные sql-запроса. Нужно для того, чтобы избежать sql-injection
    :return: None, list
    """
    con = psycopg2.connect(user=DB_USER, password=DB_PASSWD,
                           database=DB_NAME,  host=DB_HOST, port=DB_PORT)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql, data)
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    con.close()
    return rows
```

Pylint, встроенный в PyCharm, жалуется на аргумент data, говорит `dangerous-default-value`

Если позволить ему автоматически исправить код, то получится следующее:

```
def pg_select(sql: str, data = None) -> list:
    """
    SELECT
    :param sql: sql-запрос
    :param data: Данные sql-запроса. Нужно для того, чтобы избежать sql-injection
    :return: None, list
    """
    if data is None:
        data = {}
    con = psycopg2.connect(user=DB_USER, password=DB_PASSWD,
                           database=DB_NAME,  host=DB_HOST, port=DB_PORT)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql, data)
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    con.close()
    return rows
```

Я не понимаю чем опасен мой вариант с `data: dict = {}`

Объясните: **почему правильно делать именно так, как предлагает IDE, в чем заключалась моя ошибка?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аргумент по умолчанию создаётся один раз. Поэтому, если в качестве аргумента по умолчанию выбрать изменяемый тип данных (словарь или список), то он будет общим у всех вызовов функции. Соответственно, если вы один раз вызовете функцию с аргументом по умолчанию и внутри неё в этот аргумент добавите элементы, то они будут там и при следующем вызове этой функции.

Поэтому рекомендуется никогда не использовать в качестве аргумента по умолчанию объект изменяемого типа, чтобы случайно не напороться на такое поведение.